# rewriting rule for a parameter that may or may not be in the link

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want to be able to have both these addresses with one rule

```
twitter/myusername       =>  show.php?acc=twitter&username=myusernbame
twitter/myusername/json  =>  show.php?acc=twitter&username=myusernbame&output=json
```

this is what i've wrote so far and it doesn't work ... the thing is the second parameter `(json)` may or my not be in the link so the second part of the rule should cover both case

```
RewriteRule ^twitter/([0-9a-zA-Z]*)(?:/([a-zA-Z]*))$ show.php?acc=twitter&username=$1&output=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex seems incorrect, use this:

```
RewriteRule ^twitter/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)(?:/([a-zA-Z]+))?/?$ show.php?acc=twitter&username=$1&output=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```